# How can I read the db table instead of reading the property in Spring?

Tags: spring

I want to read properties from database tables instead of reading property files in Spring.

How can I achieve this? At the first time, I thought that I have to override the spring-context related classes. But I think there is easy way to implement this or Spring already provides this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I found the solution like the below link.

http://www.albinsblog.com/2014/07/loading-configuration-properties-from.html#.VNBK9Gjkep8